# Conditional loading component based on ReactRouter path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I used a React-Router, coded this

```html
<Router>
  <div className="app">
    <div className="wrapper">
      <AppHeaderMain />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/list/" component={List} />
        <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
      <div className="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><NavLink exact to="/">List</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/about/">About</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

and I have a question, is it possible to load another  component based on Rout path, for example:

```html
path="/" - load <AppHeaderMain />
path="/list/" - load <AppHeaderSubpage />
```

I know I could insert a AppHeader component into each single component but I would like to don't repeat some additional code which would be required to make that.
I mean something like conditional including (loading) component.
Is it a good practice? Maybe I must to do exactly how I wrote: include in each single component?

Comment: you can add `switch` and `route` inside of `<AppHeaderMain />` and decide how to render it. but Krasimir answer is a better practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a matter of composition. Why not create a factory function. For example:

```
function routeHandlerWithAppHeader(Component) {
  return (props) => (
    <div>
      <AppHeaderMain />
      <Component {...props}/>
    </div>;
  );
}
```

And then use:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={routeHandlerWithAppHeader(Home)} />
```

Comment: Yes, It works, but still I have to repeat this function with another AppHeaderSub, maybe pass the parameter from {this.routeHandlerWithAppHeader(About, Sub)} to AppHeader e.g. <AppHeader page={sub}>